# ¿Cómo saco las columnas de un store procedure dinámico en SQL Server?

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedure, sql

Tengo la problemática de que requiero saber las columnas de cualquier *store procedure* que pase como parámetro dentro de otro. Pero en cualquier caso no obtengo ningún resultado.

```
ALTER PROCEDURE getColumnsTable
(
    @tableColumnsNames  nvarchar(45)
)
AS 

BEGIN 

DECLARE @TSQL varchar(100)



SET @TSQL = 'select * into #TablaTemporal FROM OPENQUERY( MyServerConnection,  ''EXEC '+   @tableColumnsNames    +''');' 

EXEC (@TSQL)

SELECT COLUMN_NAME 
FROM tempdb.INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS 
WHERE TABLE_NAME like '%#TablaTemporal%'

IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM tempdb.INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS WHERE  TABLE_NAME  like  '%#TablaTemporal%' )
    BEGIN
    DROP TABLE #TablaTemporal
    END 


END
```

Este es el *store procedure* que quisiera leer

```
ALTER PROCEDURE MyProcTest AS 
BEGIN SET NOCOUNT ON; 
select c.idCliente,f.idFactura     
     from Cliente c inner join Factura f on (c.idCliente=f.idCliente)            
     where 1=2 
END
```

Quisiera obtener como resultado un

```
COLUMN_NAME
idCliente
idFactura
```

de un simple

```
 EXEC   getColumnsTable    @tableColumnsNames = N'MyProcTest'
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Finalmente he llegado a la respuesta. El exec estaba incompleto. Me respondo yo solo. Gracias por el apoyo FLixtr

```
DECLARE @sqlCompuesta varchar(MAX)
SET @sqlCompuesta='select c.idCliente,f.idFactura '+
                      'from Cliente c inner join Factura f on (c.idCliente=f.idCliente) '+
                      'where 1=1 '


EXEC (   'SELECT * into #temp1  FROM OpenQuery(MyServerConnection, '''+@sqlCompuesta+'''      )   '  +
         'SELECT * FROM tempdb.INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS '+
         'WHERE TABLE_NAME like ''%#temp1%''    '  )
```

Answer (score 1):

Dada la consulta que deseas realizar, estás interactuando directamente con el contenido de las tablas, no con la definición para obtener los nombres de las columnas. Además de que al poner la condición `where 1=2` nunca se va a cumplir y no existirán resultados en tu `SELECT`.

Para saber los nombres de las columnas debes realizar un `SELECT` directamente a la tabla donde se almacena la definición de la tabla. Yo solo pondría un *stored procedure* de la siguiente forma:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[getColumnsTable]
    @tableColumnsNames  nvarchar(45)
AS          

SET NOCOUNT ON                     
BEGIN
    SELECT C.Name FROM sys.tables T
        INNER JOIN sys.columns C 
            ON T.object_id = C.object_id
    WHERE T.name = @tableColumnsNames
END
```

Donde, la ejecución la realizarás de la siguiente forma:

```
EXEC getColumnsTable 'Cliente'
```

O en su caso:

```
EXEC getColumnsTable 'Factura'
```

Comment: Gracias poor tu respuesta Fixtr. Pero eso es para dos tablas solamente. Que pasaria si fuera una consulta de mas tablas.

Comment: Pero eso me sirve para dos tablas solamente. Que pasaria si quisiera modificar mi Store procedure y hacer una consulta con 10 o 20 tablas unidas? me seria poco practico volver a hacer joins

Comment: Lo que pasa es que con tu `JOIN` estás haciendo consultas pero al contenido de la tabla, lo que deseas obtener es la definición de la tabla. Lo que yo haría es que recibir un "*array*" de los nombres de las tablas que deseas en la variable `@tableColumnsNames`, luego, hacer la misma consulta pero en la condición poner `WHERE T.name IN (@tableColumnsNames)`

Comment: Ahora. ¿Es posible obtener las tablas de un String almacenado en un SP?

Comment: No logro captar tu pregunta, ¿podrías darme un poco más de detalle?

Comment: Hago todo este procedimiento para determinar todas las columnas de CUALQUIER Store Procedure  y almacenarlas en una estructura de datos. No he encontrado procedimiento que me devuelva las columnas que interactuan en ese store procedure. Ni tampoco procedimiento que me devuelva las Tablas de ese Store Procedure Cualquiera.

Comment: Lo mas cerca que he llegado es a la respuesta que di ahi abajo. Y en verdad se logra, pero no se almacena en la tabla temporal.

Comment: Me temo que hay una confusión en los términos, un *stored procedure* como su nombre lo indica, es un procedimiento, con tu comentario "*...todas las columnas de CUALQUIER Store Procedure...*" me parece que lo que deseas es obtener los nombres de las columnas de las tablas que tu decidas, ¿es correcto esto? Por ejemplo, si tienes las  tablas (Tabla1, Tabla2 y Tabla3, TablaN) deseas obtener el **nombre de las columnas que componen esas tablas**, es posible que yo haya caido en alguna confusión y es mejor aclarar bien para estar hablando el mismo tema.

Comment: Basicamente quiero dejar como parametro de entrada un el nombre de cualquier Store Procedure (solo select's ) y que me regrese que columnas intervinieron en el.

Comment: ¿Qué pasaría si en tu *stored procedure* tienes varios `SELECT` luego un `INSERT` y finalmente otro `SELECT`? ¿Qué resultado esperas en este caso?

Comment: Solo lo  quisiera para un  Stored Procedure sencillo de un solo SELECT por principio. Es para un API. Donde personas distintas a mi crean Store Procedure's diversos y Otro grupo de Gente Trabaja solo con el nombre de las columnas.

Answer (score 1):

A partir de SQL Server 2012, puedes usar `sys.dm_exec_describe_first_result_set` para obtener este resultado.

Tomando el stored procedure que pusistes como ejemplo:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE MyProcTest AS 
BEGIN SET NOCOUNT ON; 
select c.idCliente,f.idFactura     
     from Cliente c inner join Factura f on (c.idCliente=f.idCliente)            
     where 1=2 
END
```

Si ejecutas la consulta siguiente:

```
select name as column_name
  from sys.dm_exec_describe_first_result_set
         (N'[dbo].[MyProcTest]', null, 0)
 order by column_ordinal;
```

El resultado obtenido:

```
column_name
-----------
idCliente
idFactura
```

<kbd>[Demo](http://rextester.com/XDTJOA43856)</kbd>

Comment: Es muy buena opcion. Pero ando en SQLServer 2008 Gracias Por la respuesta.