# ¿Cómo consulto el nombre de las columnas de un Store Procedure que devuelve una consulta?

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedure, sql-server-2008

Averiguar los nombres de las columnas de `Store Procedure`. el Store Procedure devuelve una consulta, por ejemplo la consulta entre 2 tablas. He intentado hacerlo con la respuesta que encontré en la pregunta:

[¿Cómo saco las columnas de un store procedure dinámico en SQL Server?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/41272/c%C3%B3mo-saco-las-columnas-de-un-store-procedure-din%C3%A1mico-en-sql-server)

pero no me funciona.

Ejemplo: Supongamos que un Store Procedure tenga este select

```
select C.Nombre, C.Identificacion from Cliente c
```

Yo no quiero la consulta del Sp quiero que me devuelva Nombre e Identificacion

El código que utilizo es:

```
    DECLARE @sqlCompuesta varchar(MAX),
@Contrato varchar(50)
set @Contrato = 'Contrato'
SET @sqlCompuesta=   'exec SpConsultaBandaColumna ' +
                     '@Op = Null, ' +
                     '@Nombre = '+ @Contrato + ',' +
                     '@Banda = 34'

EXEC (   'SELECT * into #temp1  FROM OpenQuery(MyServerLinked, '''+@sqlCompuesta+'''      )   '  +
         'SELECT * FROM tempdb.INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS '+
         'WHERE TABLE_NAME like ''%#temp1%''    '  )
```

Comment: Los comentarios no deben usarse para discusiones extendidas; esta conversación ha sido [trasladada a un chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/51192/discussion-on-question-by-bemp14-como-consulto-el-nombre-de-las-columnas-de-un).

Answer (score 1):

Parece que OP solucionó su problema especificando el nombre de la base datos en frente del nombre del SP. Probablemente no estaba conectado a la misma base de datos donde estaba definido el SP.

Aquí dejo su comentario final:

> llamé el Store Procedure con el nombre de la Base de datos adelante y funcionó. Ejemplo: `Name_BD.dbo.Name_StoreProcedure`

Comment: Si estaba conectado a la base de datos que era, por eso es lo raro.